# How to Fix Conditional Validations in Rails Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following validation in my User model. I don't want it to run when the user is a guest, so I added an `unless` proc:

```
with_options :unless => :guest_user? do |user|
    before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
    validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
end
```

This calls the method `guest_user?` and shouldn't run when the user is a guest. However, the validation runs in all cases. How do I fix the `unless` proc so it works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
with_options :unless => :guest_user? do |o|
    o.before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
    o.validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. The Rails guide didn't say enough on this.